# Extension for Visual Studio throwing not meaningful exceptions on some PCs

Tags: c#, wpf, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

recently I've created an extension for Bitbucket using Team Explorer extensions for Visual Studio. Here it is:  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f8954a6-2358-4f4a-b69b-e51199935fad. It works fine on my machine even on clean system installation (Win 10 x64, Visual Studio 2015 community). I've also performed some tests on VDI's and everything worked perfectly. Then one of my friends reported that he gets exception after installing my plugin. The important thing is that it's reproducable so he gets it all the time. The error is not meaningful and it's being thrown by visual studio team service framework somewhere in team explorer section. I ignored this issue because I thought it's something PC related. Now yesterday another guy reported exactly the same issues. You can find them under Q and A section. I would be glad for any help, I can share the code if necessary. Some exceptions:

```
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType bamlType, Int16 


at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Controls.Commits.GitCommitsPageView.InitializeComponent()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Controls.Commits.GitCommitsPageView..ctor()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.Commits.GitCommitsPageVs.CreateView(PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Controls.GitTeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.Commits.GitCommitsPageVs.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext context)

System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Lazy`2[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WinForms.WebBrowserNavigateErrorEventArgs,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WinForms.ThemeInvariantWinformsIcons]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Lazy`2[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorerNavigationItem,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.ITeamExplorerNavigationItemMetadata]]'.
```

Comment: Maybe a framework version issue? Have you checked what version of .net framework are running affected users?

Comment: @Oscar One of affected users uses Windows 10, he hasn't installed .net framework explicitily so he has a default version of it.

Comment: Are you sure? They could have received updates through Windows Update at least..

Comment: @Oscar I just asked one of them and it's 4.6. So it's exactly the same on my development machine where it's working